# Create a VM from a raw file - Proxmox

Tags: linux, server, virtualization, kvm, proxmox

I have Proxmox environment where I create my virtual machines. I want to install the product Citrix Netscaler VPX Platinium. I downloaded the product and put it in the content of my server storage:

[image]

The file is stored as well in tgz format into the foler /usr/src of my server.
My question is : How to create a new VM from this file ? 
I only know how to create it from an ISO so ..

For example, when I click on Create new VM button it only gives to choose an Iso file, not a raw one.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Importing from raw is not as easy, try following the wikis guide: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Migration_of_servers_to_Proxmox_VE#SSH_Migration_of_a_Windows_physical_machine_to_a_VM_raw_file_directly

Comment: Have you managed to create a virtual machine from .raw image?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machine 100 ('Netscaler' ) on node 'proxmox

It basically needs to be hacked into

> 100.conf

/etc/pve/nodes/proxmox/proxmox

```
bootdisk: virtio0
cores: 2
memory: 4000
name: Netscaler 
net0: virtio=46:98:00:3A:BD:3C,bridge=vmbr0
numa: 0
onboot: 1
ostype: linux
smbios1: uuid=6c68ed9b-3939-4152-b8e9-b5c69a500d01
sockets: 1
unused0: W500:vm-100-disk-1
vga: std
virtio0: local:100/vm-100-disk-1.raw,format=raw,cache=writeback,size=250G
```